# Is it Linux or window hosting?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I Don't know much about server things.
But my client says his server is Apache version2.2, .php files run asPHP5 FastCGI

So is it Linux hosting server or Window hosting server.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not ask them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205870/how-to-determine-if-a-webserver-is-running-linux-or-windows

Answer (score 1):

You can run Apache on Linux and Windows so you can't really say what operating system is running on that server.