# Specific Image not appearing in website unless I rename it?

Tags: html, image, background, background-image

I am learning HTML. I made a website for my photography and have some photos on my home page as the background, using:

`background-image: url(&quot;images/homepage/IMAGE_NAME.jpg&quot;)`

However, I noticed there is one specific image, named "DSC_0251.jpg", that does not display unless I rename it. I thought it was the underscore or the capital letter D causing it to not display, but I have other images in the same folder, that are named similarly, such as "DSC_0704small.jpg". They both start with a capital letter and have and underscore, the latter having even more than the former. However, "DSC_0251.jpg" will not display, until I renamed it, even just calling it "1.jpg" worked. I did not change the size of the image, it is 1.4mb, and everything else is exactly the same.

In other words, this line of code works:
`background-image: url(&quot;images/homepage/DSC_0067.jpg&quot;)`

but this line does not:
`background-image: url(&quot;images/homepage/DSC_0251.jpg&quot;)`

I used Filezilla to upload the files, and I thought maybe it was because I dragged and dropped the image to the server folder directly from the location on my computer, rather than navigating to the location within Filezilla and dragging and dropping it that way, but I tried it with another similarly sized and named photo, but that one worked. I want to keep the name the same so I know what it is, and plus it's a problem that needs a solution anyway, if it comes up again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a Linux system, try checking the permissions of the file! I had a similar issue where my css and images, didn't load after copying to the new machine, for the same reason. As for windows, I don't work with them! 
Just a noobie...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For other readers, how do I know if it is a windows or a linux hosting system? I have a feeling I have to ask the host for the answer, but when you compare different hosts, they rarely list the hosting type in their pricing, so is there a test of some sort we can do to tell by ourselves?

Comment: Also what do you mean by permissions of the file? Am new to coding and technical side of web development.

Comment: Linux and windows is the operating system that the server runs. Usually, all hosting providers do publish which OS they are using . Read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205870/how-to-determine-if-a-webserver-is-running-linux-or-windows  for finding out the server OS. The permissions specifies who can access the files. Like who can read/ write/ execute.